# PhantomJS on Bamboo job running on Linux

Tags: linux, selenium, phantomjs, bamboo

I am trying to run a selenium suite via Bamboo job ( running on Linux).
It was working when I run it locally on Chrome browser but giving error when i am running it through Bamboo using phontomJS driver.

Error code is not so descriptive. Can you please give me some pointers.

```
64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
build   07-Dec-2017 17:21:23    [INFO  - 2017-12-07T06:21:23.238Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: d8dec110-db16-11e7-8dbc-41f6e101aa5b
build   07-Dec-2017 17:21:23    Dec 07, 2017 6:21:23 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
build   07-Dec-2017 17:21:23    INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
build   07-Dec-2017 17:21:23    [ERROR - 2017-12-07T06:21:23.308Z] RouterReqHand - _handle.error - {"name":"Invalid Command Method","message":"{
   \"headers\":{
      \"Accept-Encoding\":\"gzip,
      deflate\",
      \"Cache-Control\":\"no-cache\",
      \"Connection\":\"Keep-Alive\",
      \"Host\":      \"localhost:11500      \",
      \"User-Agent\":\"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_45)\"
   },
   \"httpVersion\":\"1.1\",
   \"method\":\"GET\",
   \"url\":\"/alert_text\",
   \"urlParsed\":{
      \"anchor\":\"\",
      \"query\":\"\",
      \"file\":\"alert_text\",
      \"directory\":\"/\",
      \"path\":\"/alert_text\",
      \"relative\":\"/alert_text\",
      \"port\":\"\",
      \"host\":\"\",
      \"password\":\"\",
      \"user\":\"\",
      \"userInfo\":\"\",
      \"authority\":\"\",
      \"protocol\":\"\",
      \"source\":\"/alert_text\",
      \"queryKey\":{

      },
      \"chunks\":[
         \"alert_text\"
      ]
   },
   \"urlOriginal\":\"/session/d8dec110-db16-11e7-8dbc-41f6e101aa5b/alert_text\"
}","line":202,"sourceURL":"phantomjs://code/session_request_handler.js","stack":"_handle@phantomjs://code/session_request_handler.js:202:66\n_reroute@phantomjs://code/request_handler.js:61:20\n_handle@phantomjs://code/router_request_handler.js:78:46"}
build   07-Dec-2017 17:21:23    
build   07-Dec-2017 17:21:23      phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
```

Comment: PhantomJS has been abandoned in favour of Chrome-headless. Consider switching to save yourself lot of headaches. If you still need PhantomJS, you will need to provide [mcve]. Just a dump of an error log is not very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comment. Just wondering if I can run Chrome-headless on Linux box as well.

Comment: Yes, Chrome is supported on most modern OSes.